# Reagent-Forms radio buttons displaying as text fields

Tags: clojure, radio-button, clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to display a group of radio buttons in a reagent/cljs app.  I have followed the same process from http://yogthos.github.io/reagent-forms-example.html but the radio buttons I am displaying are showing up as textfield input boxes.

```
(def ^:private options (atom nil))

(defn set-options []
(reset! options
      [{:name "label name"}
       {:name "label name"}
       {:name "label name"}])) 


(defn set-radio-buttons []
 (set-options)
   (for [option @options]
      [:div.radio
        [:label
          [:input {:field :radio}]
             (option :name)]]))



  (defn response-box []
    [:div#response
       (set-radio-buttons)])
```

I am then placing response-box in the ui layer of the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field is not a correct  input element attribute.

```
[:input {:field :radio}]
         (option :name)]]))
```

Should probably be

```
[:input {:type :radio}]
         (option :name)]]))
```

Comment: `:field` part comes from reagent-forms and is correct as per library. I have no idea why it doesn't work (it should according to reagent-form docs) but that's not a valid answer imho